# Windows wake from sleep odd behaviors

Tags: windows, sleep

When I wake my PC from sleep, pressing the windows key doesn't bring up the start menu (all other windows key combinations work and restarting windows explorer does nothing), the media player (when you press a media key to start, skip, etc.) doesn't go away. I had to download a separate program to hide the volume player from being on my screen because it will stay on top of any program forever. Another issue with Spotify occurs, Spotify will skip through 50 songs over the course of 10 seconds, then start playing a random song from the playlist, all without prompting. I also can't pick songs or playlists, skip or play previous songs. All of this goes away if I restart my computer, but this is just super annoying and is a nuisance to workflow for me. I've dealt with this for like over a year I think, reinstalling Spotify doesn't work. I'm tempted to fresh install Windows or move to Windows 11 to see if it fixes.

https://old.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/107jl4z/strange_windows_key_behavior/?context=10

This person has a similar problem, my difference is it seems to only happen when I sleep/hibernate my PC. This is the only thing I do at night, so having to restart in the morning to listen to music or have windows bring up the start menu is frustrating.

I will list out the things I have tried, mostly ideas from ChatGPT. I will add that I was troubleshooting and it said to remove conflicting software, I realized I had a keyboard software for a different keyboard installed. I uninstalled it, slept my computer and woke it, and it was fixed. I assumed that was the problem and thought well I'll just see if tomorrow if the problem even exists anymore, the next day it happened.
Troubleshoots:

- Have a different local user to see if it was attached to my user
- Update windows
- Reinstall Spotify
- Uninstall conflicting keyboard software
- Install drivers
- Run System File Checker
- Run Check Disk
- Event Viewer (didn't see any errors during the time when I woke)
- Disable unnecessary startup programs

My solution for a long time was to just restart when I wake from sleep. Sometimes I would wake my computer and the problem didn't even happen. So very strange...

Comment: [Create Power Efficiency Diagnostics Report](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html) and post online the result `.htm` file for us.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe should not occur (and does not here on multiple machines). The behaviors seem more than a simple driver update as well.

Consider:

**(1) A Windows 10 Repair Install.**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

This should also update all drivers.

As described above, the process works in lots of cases, but will not repair a damaged User Profile.

**(2) If your computer supports Windows 11,** then upgrading to Windows 11 is a good move.  Windows 10 is rapidly approaching end of life.

Given the issues you have, I would definitely do a fresh install.

I upgraded to Windows 11 1.5 years ago and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Going to Windows 11 has completely fixed the problems that were occurring. I was hesitant thinking about upgrading, but I'm happy I made the switch.

Edit: 2 months later I am still facing this issue after going to Windows 11, then fresh installing Windows 11 after facing the problem after some time. I am going to post a Power Efficiency Diagnostic Report. I don't know if anyone will even see this edit so I will probably just post again and hope that someone has a troubleshoot.

Edit 2: a few months later (11/14/2023) I invested time into not being stupid to figure this out, I realized that it was an issue with my keyboard. Went into my drivers and had extra keyboard drivers (because I would switch back and forth between two keyboards I guess?) and just removed the extra ones, hasn't occurred once since. XDXDXDDD